# Positioned Widget in Column Causes Card to Overflow

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently learning flutter and have come across an issue where the card is not staying within the boundaries of Column, but is not causing an overflow. My goal is to have the card positioned at the bottom and with Text positioned above the card.

Here is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child:
                        Image.asset("assets/testimage.jpg", fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 10.0,
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                    child: Text(
                      "A description would be going here, this is just placeholder text.",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and an image example of the problem and desired outcome

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x57ga.png)

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPRKC.png)

Comment: try to wrap your text in an exapanded widget

Comment: wrap your card with FractionallySizedBox https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define - `right: 1.0, left: 1.0,` also along with bottom in `Positioned`. widget.

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Image.network("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 1.0,
                right: 1.0,
                left: 1.0,
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "A description would be going here, this is just placeholder text.",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image]